# Android Instrumented Test: Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-testing

I've been getting this error the past few days when trying to run my android tests. Even running `ExampleInstrumentedTest` that comes from newly generated Android Studio Project fails with this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent;
class=com/google/testing/platform/proto/api/service/ServerConfigProto$ServerConfig$Builder,
method=mergeFrom(Lcom/google/protobuf/CodedInputStream;Lcom/google/protobuf/ExtensionRegistryLite;)
Lcom/google/testing/platform/proto/api/service/ServerConfigProto$ServerConfig$Builder;,
pc=15
```

I have no idea what's causing this error and how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of debugging and googling, I can't seem to find a related issue.

What seems to fix the issue was, in my Android Studio's Preferences -> Build Tools -> Gradle. Gradle JDK was set to **Java 11**. Setting it to **Java 15** or higher seems to fix it.

Now I am able to run my android tests.